# Get enum values from Enum object

Tags: java, enums

If I were to declare an enum like so

```
public enum Foo {A, B, C}
```

then I can get the enum values using

```
Foo[] values = Foo.values();
```

However if I wanted to pass Foo as a generic type, like so, I can't get the values since it's generic.

```
class Bar<E extends Enum<E>> {

    public Bar(E e) {
        E[] values = e.values(); // not possible
    }

}
```

Is it possible to iterate over the enum values any other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to pass the `Class` object:

```
 public Bar(Class<E> clazz) {
    E[] values = clazz.getEnumConstants();
 }
```

...or, if you have one element `e` of the enum, you might be able to use `e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()`.  (Don't use `e.getClass().getEnumConstants()`, which won't work if your enum constants define their own constant-specific methods.)

Another option: `EnumSet.allOf(clazz)`, which is actually more efficient than `clazz.getEnumConstants()` in many ways, since it's O(1) and not O(n) in the number of enum constants.

Comment: Was going to point out the alternative route, because that is what the OP was looking for in the code sample. :)

Comment: Ok thanks. For some reason I have to wait to accept the answer, but I'll do so.

Comment: +1 If someone is wondering why `e.values();` doesn't work, it is simply because `Enum` class doesn't have `values()` method. This method is added by compiler while extending Enum class and is equivalent of `ExtendingClass.class.getEnumConstants()`.